# Java Mail get Content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get the Content of an email, but the only thing I get is an empty String "". 
I saved an Outlook 2013 e-mail directly by drag and drop in a Folder and try to get its Content with this method.

In addition there is definitely content in the email.

```
public static String getTextContentFromMail2(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException
{
    if (p.isMimeType("text/*"))
    {
        String s = (String) p.getContent();
        //textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
        return s;
    }

    if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative"))
    {
        // prefer html text over plain text
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
        String text = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++)
        {
            Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
            if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain"))
            {
                if (text == null)
                {
                    text = getTextContentFromMail2(bp);
                }
                continue;
            }
            else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html"))
            {
                String s = getTextContentFromMail2(bp);
                if (s != null)
                {
                    return s;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return getTextContentFromMail2(bp);
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
    else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*"))
    {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++)
        {
            String s = getTextContentFromMail2(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            if (s != null)
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Just to make sure a sample Content of an email:

```
Von: Hello Hello [mailto:hello.hello@hello.hello.com] Im Auftrag von Hello-Hello-Hello.Hello
Gesendet: Donnerstag, 20. August 2015 10:33
An: Hello Hello 
Betreff: WG: Hello -Hello -Hello Hello (FROM: - Hello Hello)



Mit freundlichen Grüßen / with kind regards / 此致

Hello .-Hello . Hello Hello
```

Comment: Have you debugged your application? Are you sure you are grabbing the message you think you are grabbing?

Comment: Can you show a small sample e-mail for which this parsing fails?

Comment: I am pretty sure.  There are no other Things in this Folder. `String s = (String) p.getContent();`  always Returns an empty string

Comment: The email Content is nothing spectacular just some links and centered text. No Images or any Flash animations :)

Comment: But we can't guess if we don't see it. Please add a sample e-mail to your question. You can format it as code or use `<pre>` to make it display properly.

Comment: Added, but I dont think that this is the Problem

Comment: I have no idea what Outlook does when you drag and drop a message to a folder, but that sample message is definitely **not** a MIME format message, which is what JavaMail is expecting.  You might need to use "Save As" or something like that in Outlook to save the message in MIME format (often a .eml file).